# global keyword used in global context python

Tags: python, global

What does global keyboard used in a global context mean in python?  I know that it lets you modify global variables if used inside of a function, but I not aware of how it works when you declare a global variable using global as I thought they are already global variable when you declare outside of functions.  Like in this code below:

```
from ctypes import *

import ctypes

import os
import cv2
import time
import Image
import argparse
import numpy as np
import thread as thread

from select import select
from evdev import InputDevice

import ArducamSDK

COLOR_BYTE2RGB = 49
CAMERA_MT9F002 = 0x4D091031
SensorShipAddr = 32
I2C_MODE_16_16  = 3
usbVid = 0x52cb
Width = 4384
Height = 3288
cfg ={"u32CameraType":CAMERA_MT9F002,
      "u32Width":Width,"u32Height":Height,
      "u32UsbVersion":1,
      "u8PixelBytes":1,
      "u16Vid":0x52cb,
      "u8PixelBits":8,
      "u32SensorShipAddr":SensorShipAddr,
      "emI2cMode":I2C_MODE_16_16 }
# *********** Here is where I'm talking about****************
global saveNum,saveFlag,downFlag,flag,handle,openFlag
openFlag = False
saveNum = 0
handle = {}
downFlag = False
flag = True
saveFlag = False


regArr= [[0x301A, 0x0018],

    [0x0103, 0x1   ],  

    [0x31AE, 0x301 ],  
    [0x0112, 0x0C0C],   
    [0x301A, 0x0010],   
    [0x3064, 0x0805],   
    [0x301E, 0x00A8],   
    [0x301A, 0x10DC],   
    [0x0104, 0x1   ],  
    [0x0100, 0x0   ],  

    [0x0300, 0x4   ],  
    [0x0302, 0x01  ],  
    [0x0304, 0x03  ],  
    [0x0306, 0x6E  ],  
    [0x0308, 0x0C  ],  
    [0x030A, 0x01  ],  

    [0x3016, 0x111 ],  
    [0x0344, 0x090 ],  
    [0x0348, 0x11AF],   
    [0x0346, 0x020 ],  
    [0x034A, 0xCF7 ],  
    [0x3040, 0x0041],   
    [0x0400, 0x0   ],  
    [0x0404, 0x10  ],  
    [0x034C, 0x1120],   
    [0x034E, 0xCD8 ],  
    [0x0342, 0x33C1],   
    [0x0340, 0x0D67],   
    [0x3010, 0x00CF],   
    [0x3012, 0x0010],   
    [0x3014, 0x1F50],   
    [0x3018, 0x0000],   

    [0x0104, 0x0],  
    [0x0100, 0x1],  
    [0x0304, 8],

    [0x301a, 0x5ccc],        
    [0x3012, 500],
    [0x0206, 33],
    [0x0208, 50],
    [0x020a, 50],
    [0x020c, 33],

    [0xffff, 0xffff],
    [0xffff, 0xffff]
]


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("--type",default = "jpg",required = False, help = "type to the image file")
ap.add_argument("--name",required = False, help = "name to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

def readThread(threadName,read_Flag):
    global flag,handle
    data = {}
    cv2.namedWindow("MT9F002",1)
    while flag:
        if ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_availiable(handle) > 0:

            res,data = ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_read(handle,Width * Height)
            if res == 0:
                ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_del(handle)
            else:
                print "read data fail!"

        else:
            print "is not availiable"
        if len(data) >= Width * Height:
            show(data)
            flag = False
        else:
            print "data length is not enough!"
        if flag == False:       
            break

thread.start_new_thread( readThread,("Thread-2", flag,))

pass

def show(bufferData):
    global downFlag,saveFlag,saveNum
    image = Image.frombuffer("L",(Width,Height),bufferData)
    img = np.array(image)
    height,width = img.shape[:2]
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img,COLOR_BYTE2RGB)
        saveNum += 1

    if args["name"] != "":
                name = args["name"]   
        else:
                name = str(saveNum)
    if "bmp" == args["type"]:        
                name += ".bmp"
        if "png" == args["type"]:        
                name += ".png"
        if "jpg" == args["type"]:        
                name += ".jpg"
    cv2.imwrite(name,img2)  


def video():
    global flag,regArr,handle
    regNum = 0
    res,handle = ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_autoopen(cfg)
    capFlag = True
    if res == 0:
        openFlag = True
        print "device open success!"
        while (regArr[regNum][0] != 0xFFFF):
            ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_writeSensorReg(handle,regArr[regNum][0],regArr[regNum][1])
            regNum = regNum + 1
        res = ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_beginCapture(handle)

        if res == 0:
            print "transfer task create success!"
            while flag :
                                if capFlag:
                                        res = ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_capture(handle)
                                        if res != 0:
                                                print "capture fail!"
                                                break
                                        else:
                                                capFlag = False
                                time.sleep(0.4)
                if flag == False:       
                    break
        else:
            print "transfer task create fail!"
        res = ArducamSDK.Py_ArduCam_close(handle)
        if res == 0:
            openFlag = False
            print "device close success!"
        else:
            print "device close fail!"
    else:
        print "device open fail!"

if __name__ == "__main__":      
    video()
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the sort of thing you want to understand the behavior of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absobleepinglutely nothing. `global` is a hint to the compiler that it needs to check outer scopes for the name for code within the current scope. Since global scope is the outermost scope, there is no effect.

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...   global bar
...   bar = 1
...   baz = 2
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (bar)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (baz)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> def quux():
...   global bar
...   print bar
...   baz = 1
...   print baz
... 
>>> dis.dis(quux)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bar)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4           5 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (baz)

  5          11 LOAD_FAST                0 (baz)
             14 PRINT_ITEM          
             15 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Your examples with functions don't relate to the question. Manually `compile` code in `exec` mode to create the unoptimized code that executes at module level. The difference then -- in CPython -- is whether the code uses `LOAD_NAME` (search locals, globals, builtins) and `STORE_NAME` (store to locals) vs `LOAD_GLOBAL` (search globals, builtins) and `STORE_GLOBAL` (store to globals). For a Python module, locals and globals are the same, so there's no difference. But in a contrived example there could be a difference for `exec` executed code in which globals and locals are different.